# Searching json object and returning exact location

Tags: json, dart

I am attempting to programmatically search a JSON file for a particular section number and have it return the title index, chapter index and section index. What would be the best way to do this? See the JSON sample below:

```
{
    "book": {
        "titles": [
            {
                "title_num": "1",
                "title_name": "First Title",
                "chapters": [
                    {
                        "chapter_num": "1",
                        "chapter_name": "First chapter",
                        "sections": [
                            {
                                "section_content": "This is the first section of chapter 1.",
                                "section_num": "1.01",
                                "section_title": "section title"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "title_num": "2",
                "title_name": "Second Title",
                "chapters": [
                    {
                        "chapter_num": "8",
                        "chapter_name": "Eighth chapter",
                        "sections": [
                            {
                                "section_content": "This is the first section of chapter 8.",
                                "section_num": "8.01",
                                "section_title": "section title"
                            },
                            {
                                "section_content": "This is the second section of chapter 8.",
                                "section_num": "8.02",
                                "section_title": "section title"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }

        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have parsed the JSON into a Dart value, I'd just do something like:

```
List<int> sectionTitle(dynamic jsonData, String sectionNumber) {
  List titles = jsonData["book"]["titles"];
  for (int titleIndex = 0; titleIndex < titles.length; titleIndex++) {
    List chaptes = titles[titleIndex]["chapters"];
    for (int chapterIndex = 0; chapterIndex < chapters.length; chapterIndex++) { 
      List sections = chapters[chapterIndex]["sections"];
      for (int sectionIndex = 0; sectionIndex < sections.length; sectionIndex++) {
        if (sections[sectionIndex]["section_num"] == sectionNumber) {
          return [titleIndex, chapterIndex, sectionIndex];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return null;  // or: throw ArgumentError("section not present");
}
```

Nothing fancy, just find the lists in the JSON maps, iterate them (using an index, since you want to return those), and when you find the result, return all three indices somehow. If this is for a public API, I'd create a class for the result instead of just returning a list, since the list type doesn't promise that there is exactly three values.

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly. Learning a new language becomes much easier with people like you.